# How is this PayPal Integration secure?

Tags: paypal

Looking at this example here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/integrate/

```
payment: function(data, actions) {
  return actions.payment.create({
    transactions: [{
      amount: {
        total: '30.11',
        currency: 'USD',
        details: {
          subtotal: '30.00',
          tax: '0.07',
          shipping: '0.03',
          handling_fee: '1.00',
          shipping_discount: '-1.00',
          insurance: '0.01'
        }
      },
      description: 'The payment transaction description.',
      custom: '90048630024435',
```

This is present in the JavaScript that the client can see, how is this secure? Can the user not just modify these values and change total to a smaller value to pay less?

Similar question regarding their 'server' example which also has seemingly private information present in the client side presented JavaScript.

Comment: One common way is to use Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to validate the payment status of Paypal. When the actual paid amount is different from the required amount, the merchant will not arrange delivery and will look into the matter.

Answer (score 0):

- no you just can't change the value that way
- + even if you somehow end up changing value lets say using some kind of network spoofing thing that can override the payload, you would end up paying modified amount which the paypal & app/owner both can clearly see & validate
- which means instead of $10 if you paid $5 the app/owner would also see the same $5 & not $10
- basically you won't be able to get away depicting you paid $10 when you actually didn't pay $10

Answer (score 0):

You've linked to old archived documentation that should not be used, but the issues are the same:  Anything in client-side code can be changed. Payments can always be sent for a lower amount. That's how client side payments work.

---

Any logic to keep track of which payments are valid and for the correct amount must be on your server.

For PayPal Checkout, here's the front-end UI you should use: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You'll need two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

Validate correctness when capturing on the server. If it's wrong, don't capture.